# How to make JAX-WS webservice respond with specific http code

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, glassfish-3

Just like the title says.

```
    @WebService(
        targetNamespace = "http://com.lalaland.TestWs",
        portName = "TestWs",
        serviceName = "TestWs")
public class TestWs implements TestWsInterface {

    @EJB(name="validator")
    private ValidatorLocal validator;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "getStuff")
    public List<StuffItem> getStuff(@WebParam(name = "aaa")String aaa, 
                        @WebParam(name = "bbb")int bbb )  {

          if ( ! validator.check1(...) ) 
               return HTTP code 403        <------------ Here
          if ( ! validator.check2(...) )
               return HTTP code 404        <------------ Here
          if ( ! validator.check3(...) ) 
               return HTTP code 499        <------------ Here

          return good list of Stuff Items

    }
```

Is there anyway I can make a method return a specific HTTP code on demand? I know that some of the stuff, like authentication, internal server errors , etc  make the the WS method return 500 and auth errors , but I would like to be able to send these in accordance with by business logic.

Anyone done this before? Been using jax-WS for some time and this was the first time I had this need, tried searching for it and couldn't find an answer anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Just for completeness sake , I already tried : throw new javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException(123) and it didn't work

Comment: which one are you using: metro or cxf?

Comment: @Chechus this is being deployed on Glassfish 3 , so metro, forgot to mention this and just placed the glassfish-3 tag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only get the current instance of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` and sends the error.

```
@WebService
public class Test {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "testCode")
    public String testCode(@WebParam(name = "code") int code) {
        if (code < 200 || code > 299) {
            try {
                MessageContext ctx = context.getMessageContext();
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) 
                        ctx.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_RESPONSE);
                response.sendError(code, code + " You want it!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.severe("Never happens, or yes?");
            }
        }
        return code + " Everything is fine!";
    }

}
```

See also [*List of HTTP status codes - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Create a SoapHandler like this: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/ implementing the interface: Handler.handleResponse();

then, inside the handler you are avalaible to modify as you like the http headers, so you can add something like: http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html

Where you can use the: **HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE** as you want.

Other resource: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13735/handlers.htm

Tip: think on soaphandlers as interceptors for soap messages

Comment: Testing it now. Will let you know in a minute or two

Comment: by **Handler.handleResponse();** you mean handleMessage() ? Can't find the signature for handleResponse.

Comment: you will find how to do it in the oracle tutorial, but in fact the Paul response is pretty cleaner, try it if you just need change http response codes.